# Can't get website to auto-size

Tags: html

I have been working on a website for my job (Don't worry its not web design) and am having some problems. I only know a very tiny bit of HTML and this is what I came up with. They say that is perfectly fine, but the website will not auto size. Here is the code below. I appreciate all the help!

Here is the site,
http://www.stateofusing.org/

Comment: Might be responsiveness?

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your background image:

```
style="width:100%; height:auto;"
```

This will make your backgorund to use 100% of the screen.
If you want everything reziable add this to your body tag.

can also add to css file if you have one

Hope it helps